# Approaching the label at timer, it can's renewal string of label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer, label

I make a Voca App.
After playing voice file and showing English text, it shows the meaning label.
So, I want to hide label texts before playing next voice file.

I have problem.df
These labels are not hidden.

Approaching the label at timer, it can's renewal string of label.

What is the problem?
Help me, please!

---

```
- (void)showLabel{

    Word *word = [wordArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
    [simpleMeaning setText:word.mean];

    NSTimer *timer2 = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
    [timerArray addObject:timer2];
    [timer2 release];
    timer2 = nil;


}

- (void)hideLabel{

    [simpleMeanig setText:@" "];
    ++selectedIndex;
    [self filePlay];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondering if the call to filePlay is blocking the UI update (hard to tell without seeing the guts of filePlay).

This is just a guess, but instead of:

```
[self filePlay];
```

try:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:(@selector(filePlay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This will defer the call to filePlay until after the current event (as a result of the timer firing) has been processed (which should in turn should allow the UI to refresh itself).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. In fact I find the reason. I made typo-label's name. Thank you very much.